# How can I set Crontab for a specific hour?

Tags: php, cron

I'd like to set my Cron job to work at specific hour.
Particularly, I'd like to set it at 1PM and 7PM every day of the year. How can I do?
I wrote two line like those below:

```
0 13 * * * /usr/bin/php path/myphp.php
0 19 * * * /usr/bin/php path/myphp.php
```

but nothing works fine! Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0 13,19 * * * /usr/bin/php path/myphp.php` should work, check your log / user mail for errors.

Comment: I just set as you suggest...I'll give you info

Comment: when you run `/usr/bin/php path/myphp.php` what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that there's a difference in format between a user's crontab (accessed with the command `contab -e` or what have you) and the system's crontab, managed in files like /etc/cron.d and others.

In a user's personal crontab, the format you used should work. 
In the system crontab, (if you place a new file or edit anything under /etc), make sure you specify the user name to run as before the command, for example:

```
0 13,19 * * * www-data /usr/bin/php path/myphp.php
```

Will run the command `/usr/bin/php path/myphp.php` as user `www-data` every day at 13:00 and 19:00.

Comment: Sorry...I'm stupid :-) It's ok. It works fine. Thanks a lot for your suggest.